# Difficulty with special characters in hash key names in perl

Tags: perl, hash

I am having a very difficult time getting this simple script to work in Perl
I have two Hashes, the keys of which are similar to email addresses.
I really believe my problem is interpreting the "@" and "." symbols in the keys

I have verified that the hash keys are correct and in test data exist 
All keys are lower case

when the program runs it creates the hashes as thus....

```
###  $UPN here is "joesnuffy@apples.grumpy.com"
$AD_Master_List{$UPN}="$DN,$FN,$LN,$UPN,$Email,$JobTitle,$Dept";

###  $UPN2 here is "joesnuffy@apples.grumpy.com"
$HTE_Master_List{$UPN2}="$EN,$RFN,$MI,$RLN,$RPT,$RDPT,$UPN,$EMAIL";}

#####   The failing Code snippet is below

foreach $A (keys(%HTE_Master_List))
{
  unless (exists ($AD_Master_List{$A}))
    {print "$A is not present in Active Directory\n";}
}
```

and the checking for a match won't work....
Any help that anybody might have would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Rick Crumlich

I apologize.. I only provided a snippet..

I use strict warnings.and have all  variables predefined.

I was going to upload the whole code block but it was 250 lines and I thought it would be overkill.

my data check shows the correct 'literal version of the $UPN' but in the matching is where it fails.

As noted I am sure the problem is interpolation of the @ and Period in the string.

I do appreciate everybody who looked over my snippet.

Comment: How does it fail? What output do you get?

Comment: 1)  Do you have `use strict` and `use warnings`?  2) What is `Data::Dumper` telling you about the contents of %HTE_Master_List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you have shown works.  See it run [here](https://ideone.com/RSFJkH).

You have some other error in your code.

*Note:*

If you define `$UPN` with double quotes, your code will fail, because it will try to interpolate an array.

```
#wrong: tries to interpolate nonexistent array @apples
my $UPN = "joesnuffy@apples.grumpy.com";

#right
my $UPN = 'joesnuffy@apples.grumpy.com';
```

This problem would be caught if you used `warnings` and `strict`, however.  It is clear that you are not using strict, because the above code fails (due to failure to declare `$A`).